# How to install beautiful soup 4 with python 2.7 on windows

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have windows vista with Python 2.7. I would like to install BeautifulSoup 4 but apparently I can't install Beautiful Soup just by copying the file into the site-packages directory.
I have to install pip and then run some commands from the command prompt.
Could you guide me through it step by step?

Comment: First part: [How to install pip on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't **need** `pip` for installing Beautiful Soup - you *can* just download it and run `python setup.py install` from the directory that you have unzipped BeautifulSoup in (assuming that you have added Python to your system `PATH` - if you haven't and you don't want to you can run `C:\Path\To\Python27\python "C:\Path\To\BeautifulSoup\setup.py" install`)

However, you really *should* install `pip` - see [How to install pip on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806) for how to do that best (via @MartijnPieters comment)

Comment: If you do have pip installed use run "pip install beautifulsoup4"

Comment: I agree with Sean. Do these steps;

Comment: I think most installations of python come with `pip` at this point in time.

Answer (score 22):

```
easy_install BeautifulSoup4
```

or

```
easy_install BeautifulSoup
```

to install easy_install

```
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files
```

Answer (score 20):

**Install pip**

Download [get-pip](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py). Remember to save it as "get-pip.py"

Now go to the download folder. Right click on **get-pip.py** then open with **python.exe**.

**You can add system variable by**

**(by doing this you can use pip and easy_install without specifying path)**

1 Clicking on Properties of **My Computer**

2 Then chose **Advanced System Settings**

3 Click on **Advanced** Tab

4 Click on **Environment Variables**

5 From **System Variables** >>> select variable **path**.

6 Click edit then add the following lines at the end of it

```
 ;c:\Python27;c:\Python27\Scripts
```

(please dont copy this, just go to your python directory and copy the paths similar to this)

NB:- you have to do this once only.

**Install beautifulsoup4**

Open **cmd** and type

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Answer (score 6):

I feel most people have pip installed already with Python. On Windows, one way to check for pip is to open Command Prompt and typing in:

```
python -m pip
```

If you get **Usage** and **Commands** instructions then you have it installed.
If `python` was not found though, then it needs to be added to the path. Alternatively you can run the same command from within the installation directory of python.

If all is good, then this command will install BeautifulSoup easily:

```
python -m pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

Screenshot:

[image: Installing very very beautiful soup]

N' now I see I need to upgrade my pip, which I just did :)