# Couldn't import `beautifulSoup` in python 2.7 and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to import `beautifulSoup` but getting an error.Could you please tell me why so or guide me to resolve the same?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Arup Rakshit>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Arup Rakshit>ipython
'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Arup Rakshit>cd..

C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd Python27

C:\Python27>cd C:\Python27\selenv\Scripts

C:\Python27\selenv\Scripts>my_selenium_script.py
hello

C:\Python27\selenv\Scripts>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> from beautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named beautifulSoup
>>>
```

**EDIT**

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
>>> 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

> > >

**EDIT1**

```
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'url' is not defined
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(https://demo.aravo.com))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(https://demo.aravo.com))
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(https://demo.aravo.com/))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(https://demo.aravo.com/))
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(demo.aravo.com/))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(demo.aravo.com/))
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(demo.aravo.com))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'demo' is not defined
>>>
```

**UPDATE**

```
C:\>cd C:\Python27\selenv\Scripts

C:\Python27\selenv\Scripts>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("https://demo.aravo.com/"))
>>> tables = source.findAll('td')
>>> import csv
>>> writer = csv.writer(open('filename.csv','w'))
>>> writer.writerow(rows)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'rows' is not defined
>>>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Umm... It looks like Python hasn't been added to your PATH variable for a start... What is happening in `my_selinuim_script.py`?

Comment: @Ben `my_selinuim_script.py` giving me the output `hello`. I think its OKay!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try capitalizing `BeautifulSoup`

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

And if you are using BS4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

As Intelligently suggested by @poke, ensuring that you have `BeautifulSoup` installed is key :) Try this, which discusses BS installation on Windows:  [How to install beautiful soup 4 with python 2.7 on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228102/how-to-install-beautiful-soup-4-with-python-2-7-on-windows)

Comment: And if neither of that worked, you need to [install](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download) it first.

Comment: @user1897085 Then you need to install Beautiful Soup…

Comment: Which version you want me to install, as I am using windows - 7 and python 2.7

Comment: @user1897085 Beautiful Soup 4, as explained in the link under the heading “Download Beautiful Soup”.

Comment: Shall I install `beautifulsoup4-4.1.3.tar.gz' ?

Comment: Sorry, had to step away for a bit, but @poke's suggestion is definitely the right one (guess I should have thought of that first :) ).

Comment: @user1897085 Not at a computer, but to piggyback on poke's suggestion, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228102/how-to-install-beautiful-soup-4-with-python-2-7-on-windows for installation instructions on Windows.

Comment: @peter see my **EDIT1**. Please help!

Comment: @user1897085 That needs to be enclosed in quotes as it is a string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21735/discussion-between-rocketdonkey-and-user1897085)