# Python - RSS Web Scraping - Selecting Correct Elements

Tags: python, xml, rss

I posted an article to help with the output format of data I had scraped from an RSS feed.

The answer I received was exactly what I needed and the output format is now as required.

The updated code is as follows:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar
import time

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]

def main():
    try:
        page = 'http://feeds.link.co.uk/thelink/rss.xml'
        sourceCode = opener.open(page).read()

        try:
            titles = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>',sourceCode)
            desc = re.findall(r'<description>(.*?)</description>',sourceCode)
            links = re.findall(r'<link>(.*?)</link>',sourceCode)
            pub = re.findall(r'<pubDate>(.*?)</pubDate>',sourceCode)

            for i in range(len(titles)):
                print titles[i]
                print desc[i]
                print links[i]
                print pub[i]
                print ""

        except Exception, e:
            print str(e)

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

main()
```

This runs and outputs to console as I wanted it to, but I receive a 'list index out of range' error when it completes as the elements are not matching count.

The xml I am pulling the data from has some elements in the header which use ,  and  which cause the title, descriptions and link to be out of sequence and cause the error.

The xml is as follows:

```
<rss>  
  <channel> 
    <title>Title1</title>  #USING THIS WOULD BE OK, BUT **
    <link>http://link.co.uk</link>  
    <description>The descriptor</description>  
    <language>en-gb</language>  
    <lastBuildDate>Sat, 18 Jan 2014 06:32:19 GMT</lastBuildDate>  
    <copyright>Usable</copyright>  
    <image> #**THIS IS THE AREA I WANT TO EXCLUDE!!
      <url>http://link.co.uk.1gif</url>  
      <title>Title2</title> #DONT WANT THIS ELEMENT!! 
      <link>http://link.co.uk/info</link>  
      <width>120</width>  
      <height>60</height> 
    </image>  #**THIS IS THE AREA I WANT TO EXCLUDE!!
    <ttl>15</ttl>  
    <atom:link href="http://thelink" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>  ###
    <item> #I WANT TO START THE SCRAPE FROM HERE!!
      <title>Title3</title>  
      <description>This will be the first decription.</description>  
      <link>http://www.thelink3.co.uk</link>  
      <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.thelink.co.uk/5790820</guid>  
      <pubDate>Sat, 18 Jan 2014 09:53:10 GMT</pubDate>  
    </item>  
    <item> 
      <title>Title4</title>  
      <description>This will be the second description.</description>  
      <link>http://www.thelink3.co.uk/second link</link>  
      <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.thelink.co.uk/5790635</guid>  
      <pubDate>Sat, 18 Jan 2014 09:56:14 GMT</pubDate>   
    </item>  #I WANT THE SCRAPE TO END HERE
</rss>
```

Is there a way to change the python code to ensure it misses the header elements and just uses the common ones below this?

I have examined a few RSS feeds and they are created the same way, so I code use this code and change the URL to scrape from several RSS feeds for use on the raspberry Pi console.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using BeautifulSoup4? It will be a lot easier to find the elements you want.

With code like this:

```
title = soup.find('title')
if title:
    print title.text
```

Also, to not get the "Elements out of range error, you could check first if you have enough elements in the list:

```
if len(titles) < i: # Doens't have the index
    return
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Is BeautifulSoup available for Windows platform? Sorry I should have mentioned I am writing the code on Python for Windows and will port to Linux when it is ready.

Comment: @Zeeman Yes, it is available for Windows. To install with `pip`, do `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: I'm not used to using python in windows, but if you have `pip`, I'd say that you can install BeautifulSoup on windows, here is a relevant post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228102/how-to-install-beautiful-soup-4-with-python-2-7-on-windows

Comment: All up and running with BeautifulSoup4 on Windows. Back to coding now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a proper xml parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), rather than regexes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = sourceCode # your sourceCode variable from your main() function

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for item in soup.find_all('item'):
    for tag in ['title', 'description', 'link', 'pubdate']:
        print(tag.upper(), item.find(tag).text)
    print()
```

Output:

```
TITLE Title3
DESCRIPTION This will be the first decription.
LINK 
PUBDATE Sat, 18 Jan 2014 09:53:10 GMT

TITLE Title4
DESCRIPTION This will be the second description.
LINK 
PUBDATE Sat, 18 Jan 2014 09:56:14 GMT
```

Comment: Yes, I could use BeautifulSoup but the code is almost doing the job I require. I only need to select the correct elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what can I say????

BeautifulSoup could have saved me a lot of typing :)

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://feeds.link.co.uk/thelink/rss.xml"
sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

data = sourceCode 

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for item in soup.find_all('item'):
    for tag in ['title', 'description', 'link', 'pubdate']:
        print(tag.upper(), item.find(tag).text)
    print()
```

Comment: and with a time.sleep(10) function added it works a treat. Thank you all for the help.