# print text with underline in python

Tags: python

I have tried the below code for finding the underlined text in a html file, but it is not working.

```
f=open("jk.html","r")
while True:
    for line in f.read():
        for i in line.split():
            j=i.find("<ul>")
            k=i.find("</ul>")
            for m in range(j, k):
                print(m)

f.close()
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
   <ul> hill </ul>
   <p> millfhhf </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for parsing html content, it is advised to use one of python's xml parse module.

Comment: Btw `<ul>` is *unordered list*. `<u>` is underlined text.

Comment: If you're expecting that `while` loop to break, you're going to be waiting a while.

Answer (score 1):

This becomes really simple if you use the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module, which is going to be far better at parsing HTML (especially if it is messy HTML).

```
import bs4

f = open("test.html")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f)

for underlined in soup.find_all('u'):
    print underlined.get_text()
```

Also, the tag for underlined text in HTML is <u>

```
<html>
<body>
   <p>
       <u> hill </u>
       <u> millfhhf </u>
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to install it.  It isn't included with Python by default.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 7 operating system

Comment: You'll want to install it either using pip or easy_install (obtained with the python setuptools).  See this stackoverflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228102/how-to-install-beautiful-soup-4-with-python-2-7-on-windows) for instructions.

Comment: Did that help, were you able to get bs4 installed?

Answer (score 0):

This code does not work because `read()` returns the rest of the file and then you iterate over it char by char. For lines use `readline()` or just iterate over the file:

```
for line in fp:
    # do whatever
```

That said, use [htmlparser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or an XML parser for any reliable parsing.

Also, the tag for the underlining is `<u>`, not `<ul>`.

Comment: `read` doesn't return the next character, it returns the whole rest of the file.

Comment: CAN U TELL ME HOW TO USE HTML PARSER

Comment: @SumeettenDoeschate see [@mdadm's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22574349/770830).

Comment: @SumeettenDoeschate Don't shout, please.