# How to Install BeautifulSoup correctly on Windows 7

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a web scraper project and I see from tutorials that I will need BeautifulSoup.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to download it.

I'm using Windows 7, installed Python 2.7.9 and have successfully downloaded lxml through the exe file at Pypi. I saw the post: ([How to install beautiful soup 4 with python 2.7 on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228102/how-to-install-beautiful-soup-4-with-python-2-7-on-windows)) and tried following the steps, but can't get it to download even if I have the extracted .tar file of BS4.

Could someone give a guide of how to install BS4 please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `pip` installed?

`pip install beautifulsoup4` is probably the easiest way to install Beautiful Soup. If you have `easy_install`, `easy_install beautifulsoup4` will also install it correctly.

Comment: I have those in my Scripts folder under Python27, I ran the easy_intstall-2.7.exe file. Do I then go into powershell and run easy_install beautifulsoup4?

Comment: Just running easy_install-2.7.exe won't do anything. It's meant to be run from the command line, with arguments passed to it. Open up the command prompt/powershell and run `easy_install beautifulsoup4`